# How to send command to running program? in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a program named myProgram.exe that's running in console on a server. On the server I can type a command in the console and it works.
On the client side, how I send command to this console using a batch file. I would like to attach to this console and pass to it a command in one line. It's possible?

Server: Windows 2003 Server
Client: Windows XP or Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed solution with `remote.exe`

On Server 'A': 
`remote /s cmd bootSession`

On Client 'B':
`createSession.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo remote /s cmd session1 > commands.txt
echo @q >> commands.txt
remote /c A bootSession < commands.txt
del commands.txt
remote /c A session1
```

If you think about haveing more than one session you should run a counter on your client and embed client name + counter in the `uid`.

You could create random uid's, too.

Comment: Thanks, It works, just in second line echo remote /s cmd session1 > commands.txt

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use PSEXEC (SysInternals)

```
psexec \\%SERVER% c:\FOLDER\FILE.EXE
```

Comment: This would work to execute program there, not send commands to it.

Comment: this will help you host your program from the client side if it's based on cmd gui

Comment: Right, had to reread his question 2 more times to get what he wants.

Comment: Ha! This is what I'm working on. I would to replace the tool psexec because we dn't have permission to distribute it with our product.  
I think it is impossible to send command to program running in console on Windows (Where is the first response?). Thanks for all

Comment: Other things, I use the tool remote.exe to replace psexec. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , in this example, they use KD or CDB, me I use cmd instead of

Comment: Well i wanted to propose using remote.exe ... so what is your question?

Comment: I remote a session in computer A by: remote /s cmd bootSession. I connect to this from computer B by: remote /c A bootSession. Always in computer B I type remote /s cmd session1 to remote another session in computer A. Then I type @Q to quit bootSession and remote /c A session1 to connect to session1. Now I would like todo this in one batch file.
Look, the bootSession still mounted in computer A for other computer

Comment: Make a commands.txt on client where you put your commands you'd like to send to the remote host (server), then on client call `remote /c A bootSession < commands.txt` Now in your case commands.txt would contain the lines `remote /s cmd session1` and `@q`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code createSession.bat in client B:

```
@echo off
echo remote /s cmd session1 > commands.txt
echo @Q >> commands.txt
runas /profile /savecred /user:User1"cmd /C %RemotePath%\remote /c computerA bootSession   < %CD%\commands.txt" 
runas /profile /savecred /user:User1"cmd /k %RemotePath%\remote /c computerA session1"
```

It works fine, but the first instance of cmd (bootSession) still open even i send @Q to remote to quit. You have idea to close it and let just the second instance (session1).

Thanks another time

Comment: I have tried this but it not work :
runas /profile /savecred /user:User1"cmd /C (%RemotePath%\remote /c computerA bootSession   < %CD%\commands.txt) & exit"

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I did not see that you have posted another question as an answer!
Well the problem with your code is that you no longer provide remote.exe with the stdin from commands.txt but runas wich does not parse it to it's child process.
Try removing the runas from the batch file and instead calling the batchfile via runas.

Comment: I used: taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Remote /C ComputerB ""bootSession""" /T

Comment: So you want to close the 'bootSession' instance of cmd? Then you could add an `echo exit > commands.txt` right before `echo @q > commands.txt` ...